# Multi-Device Application with platform specific inclusions in the uses clause for Delphi XE8

Tags: android, ios, delphi, delphi-xe8

I have an mobile application written in Delphi XE8 that I can deploy to either Android or iOS from two separate projects.  The only reason for maintaining separate projects is the different destination platforms have different "uses" sections that will not compile ...

With ANDROID as the destination :

```
uses 
  ...
  FMX.Layouts, FMX.ListView,
  FMX.PhoneDialer,
  IdURI,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.Provider,
  AndroidApi.Jni.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.Net,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, Androidapi.JNI.Telephony,
  AndroidAPI.Helpers,
  AndroidApi.Jni.App,
  Androidapi.IOUtils, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, Data.DBXDataSnap, IPPeerClient, ... ;
```

With IOS as the destination :

```
uses 
...
  FMX.Layouts, FMX.ListView,
  FMX.PhoneDialer,
  ///// iOS Only ///////////
  MacApi.Helpers, iOSapi.UIKit,
  ///// iOS Only ///////////
  IdURI, IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders_Static,
  System.IOUtils,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, Data.DBXDataSnap, IPPeerClient, ... ;
```

I have tried placing {ifdef IOS} uses ... {Else} uses .... {EndIf IOS} to define two separate uses statements for two different destination platforms, but that would not compile.

Any helpful advice would be greatly appreciated. 
-- ImageBASE

Comment: Works for me. When you attempt to compile, it should point you towards the problem unit in your Use Clause if for some reason your are using {$IFDEF IOS} right and there maybe a something not encapsulated when it should be.

Comment: You missed the `$` char, didn't you ? It should be e.g. `{$ifdef...}`, not `{ifdef...}`, otherwise you wrote just comments.

Comment: TLama always posting answers as comments...

Comment: There should be some sort of award for "stupidest question asked to date."  Thank you TLama, hope that didn't hurt your brain.

Comment: Oh believe me, I've seen some really, really dumb questions here. You're well above them.

Comment: You probably want to wrap this up a little more comprehensively so that you contain thee conditional code as much as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TLama pointed out, it appears you're missing the `$` character. Without it, these are treated merely as comments. What you should do is...

```
{$IFDEF IOS}
...
{$ELSE}
...
{$ENDIF}
```

Or:

```
{$IFDEF IOS}
...
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
...
{$ENDIF}
```

For example:

```
uses 
...
  FMX.Layouts, FMX.ListView,
  FMX.PhoneDialer,
  {$IFDEF IOS}
  ///// iOS Only ///////////
  MacApi.Helpers, iOSapi.UIKit,
    {$IFDEF CPUARM}
  // iOS Devices Only
  IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders_Static,
  // iOS Devices Only
    {$ENDIF}
  ///// iOS Only ///////////
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
  ///// Android Only ///////////
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.Provider,
  AndroidApi.Jni.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.Net,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, Androidapi.JNI.Telephony,
  AndroidAPI.Helpers,
  AndroidApi.Jni.App,
  Androidapi.IOUtils,
  ///// Android Only ///////////
  {$ENDIF}
  IdURI,
  System.IOUtils,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,
  IdTCPClient, IdHTTP, Data.DBXDataSnap, IPPeerClient, ... ;
```

Comment: @Remy Thanks for the edit, I was hoping it was self-explanatory for OP. But I see you also added some new much needed conditionals OP may not have been aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Other way

```
{$IF Defined(MSWINDOWS) or Defined(MACOS)} 
// some code
{$ENDIF}
```